# Rstudio server as an iframe on windows

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I wanted to have R Studio server that enables accessing R Studio from a browser in my web application . I have seen earlier that we could do that using iframe.

But R studio server was only meant for ubuntu/linux kind , Not windows. How do I add R Studio as an Iframe in my app in windows ?

Comment: This shows how to run RStudio Server on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792090/install-r-studio-server-on-windows

Comment: That requires virtual box right . Any other way to do it like running an apache

Comment: There are no binaries for it on Windows and I have not seen any serious attempts to port it to Windows (tons of dependencies & complexities). The source is available if you want to try to give it a whirl, but your best best is to virtualize it.